# Failure intensity and survival functions.

Tags: probability

My problem is as follows:

> We have six components in series, when one of them fails we say that the
> system fails. All components share the same failure intensity function
> $\lambda(t)=t,\,\, t\geq 0$

**How do I find the probability of the system breaking down exactly on day
$6$**? I already found the survival function $R(t)=e^{-3t^2}$.

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or what you tried would be a big step forward!

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- What is the probability none of the components fail in the first $5$ days?
- What is the probability at least one of the components fails in the first $5$ days?
- What is the probability none of the components fail in the first $6$ days?
- What is the probability at least one of the components fails in the first $6$ days?
- What is the probability none of the components fail in the first $5$ days and at least one of the components fails on the $6$th day?